# Replay special macro in Vim

Tags: vim, macros

I know there are a lot of answares replaying a macro, however I cant get them to work on this specific macro.

```
8g8mmxuGojjp`ml
```

This macro will find the next illegal character and past in on the bottom of the file.

```
8g8 - find the next illegal char.
mm  - mark the spot.
xu  - cut and undo to have the char in the " register.
Go  - jump to the bottom of the file and open a new line.
jj  - my shortcut to exit insert mode.
p   - paste the char.
`m  - jump back to the oreginal location.
l   - move one step to the left. ofherwise 8g8 will just find the same char again...
```

Trying to run this on the entier file dose not work.

I tryed

```
:%morm! @q
```

also with visual select...

any ideas?

Comment: I would have upvoted, but the abundant typos make this hard to follow. Vim has built-in spell checking; please use it next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this should work (ignoring your typos, insistence of using the `jj` mapping together with `:norm!`, etc. as others have already remarked).

The problem is your implementation of obtaining the bad character by deleting and undoing. Somehow, Vim joins the pasting at the end of the buffer with the next deletion, so your paste effectively disappears, as if it never happened. (I still see some messages that indicate it is doing the thing, especially the undoing of the `o` command.)

Fortunately, this can be easily avoided, because there's a better command for yanking the current character (without undo): `yl`

This will do (note that the `^[` is a literal Escape character, inserted via `<C-V><Esc>`):

```
:let @q = '8g8mmylGo^[p`ml'
:%norm! @q
```

However, this still isn't right. `8g8` will move to following lines, so if you execute this on *every line*, you'll have duplicates (unless there are bad characters on every line), and miss subsequent bad characters in a line!

Better make this a *recursive macro* by appending the macro invocation at the end:

```
let @q = '8g8mmylGop`ml@q'
:1norm! @q
```

As you paste at the end of the buffer, these pastes will also be processed by the macro, potentially endlessly. Better yank to an *uppercase register* to accumulate the bad characters inside the register, and then only paste at the end of the macro execution. I'll leave that to you, for further learning :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, it's `:norm`, not `:morm`.

Second, `:norm!` is non-recursive so it's `jj` that will be executed, not `<Esc>`. You will need to use `:norm` (without the bang) if you want to use a mapping in your macro.

See `:help :normal`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, it's a typo... I ment norm!
anyway, It still will not run on the hole file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ingo, here is the solution:

```
qaq - fast way to clear reg a.
qqq - fast way to clear reg q.
```

`8g8"Ayll@q`

```
8g8 - find the next bad char.
"Ayl - Yank the current cher and append to reg a.
l - to move to the next char.
@q - repeat the macro.
```

run the macro using:
`:1norm! @q`

at the end, all the bad chars are in reg a.

Comment: Instead of posting your own answer, you should have accepted my answer instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to asking questions on Stackoverflow.
I was not aware of the importance...

Comment: No problem; you can still accept an answer by clicking on the outlined arrow next to it. And if you don't want to remove your own answer, at least add some basic markup to format it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you try using <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of `jj` just to see if is this your problem?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunantly, this did not solve the problem.